# CWAC Camera crash on NPE on Motorola Device

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm having trouble even opening up the CameraDemo-V9 application (Using version 0.6 of the library). The hardware I'm testing on is a Motorola Droid Razr Maxx HD. This is currently the only physical device I have access to, but the library worked on this phone when it was around version 0.4.2. I'm getting this in logcat:

```
    02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.setHost(CameraView.java:87)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment.onCreateView(CameraFragment.java:40)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5068)
02-17 16:38:17.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
```

Which seems to happen on this line:

`if (host.getDeviceProfile().useTextureView()) {`

of this method:

```
public void setHost(CameraHost host) {

    this.host = host;
    if (host.getDeviceProfile().useTextureView()) {
        previewStrategy = new TexturePreviewStrategy(this);
    } else {
        previewStrategy = new SurfacePreviewStrategy(this);
    }

}
```

I feel as though this might just be a problem with how I'm setting up the library now as I'm not importing any jars, I just downloaded the zip, and I'm importing the two library projects. Can anyone confirm that my settup seems to be "legal"? The only other idea I had was to check for previous issues, but it seem that this [one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/104) might have been resolved already because of when the latest version (6.0) was released. Maybe this is because they are both motorola devices, but maybe that is an incorrect assumption?

*Note: I get a crash before I see anything on the screen at all. No preview or anything.*

Comment: try adding a check `if(host != null && host.getDeviceProfile().useTextureView()) {` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, because I don't have enough Motorola devices in my portfolio and missed a flaw in my new `getDefaultProfile()` implementation. Track [the bug that you linked to](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/104) and watch for an 0.6.1 release soonish. My apologies for the hassle, and thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Got your fix. Much appreciated. Curious to as of why most of your device profiles are commented out but the XT890 has to stay?

Comment: @user2676468: No good way to implement that one in an XML resource, as it requires runtime data. I may try to finagle some means of using a `boolean` value in the XML to toggle between different behaviors. For the moment, as it's the only device with this oddity that I have encountered, I'm settling for the hard-coding.